# re-installing windows 10 insider preview

Tags: reinstall, windows-10-preview, windows-10

If a Windows 10 Insider Preview user need to re-install from scratch the final windows 10 pro on the same computer what serial need to use?
Are the Insider Preview credentials logon enough?
I cannot find info on this case online.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to buy a license. Only windows 7 and windows 8 users are eligible to apply for the free upgrade.

If you have an old windows 7 or 8 license, install that windows first, then use the upgrade function to register your hardware ID. This should allow you to install windows 10 in the future without a problem.

Comment: May I ask if you have a link to an official documentation about that? thanks.

Comment: My collegue who was running windows insider was unable to install and needed a key. He used one of our MSDN license keys as there was no other way. This is not a link, but experience. The rest is accumulaetd through various answers here on SuperUser.